# knowledge__kav: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, field-update, null-pointer

I am unable to fix the error
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object on my trigger.

Could someone help?
Thanks

```
trigger Knowledge_kavKnownErrorSubscription on Knowledge__kav (after insert, after update) {

List<Known_Error_Subscription__c> kesList = new List<Known_Error_Subscription__c>();

for(Knowledge__kav kav : [SELECT Id, Known_Error_Status__c, VersionNumber, Title, KnowledgeArticleId, (SELECT Knowledge__c FROM Known_Errors_Subscriptions__r)
                          FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]) {
                             
     if(kav.KnowledgeArticleId != null &&(Trigger.oldMap.get(kav.Id).LastPublishedDate != Trigger.newMap.get(kav.Id).LastPublishedDate)) {
        Known_Error_Subscription__c kes = kav.Known_Errors_Subscriptions__r;
        kes.Knowledge__c = kav.KnowledgeArticleId;
        kesList.add(kes);
        
    }
                              
}
if(kesList.size() > 0) {
    update kesList;
}


}
```

Comment: Objects in relationships do not appear in trigger context until queried. So you will have to query `Known_Errors_Subscriptions__r`, until which it will be null, and you will get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

When it run on insert, Trigger.oldMap is empty, so when you say

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(kav.Id)
```

it will return NULL, and then when you say

```
Trigger.oldMap.get(kav.Id).LastPublishedDate
```

it will give you the null pointer exception, since you are trying to get something on a NULL.

It's also possible you get a NULL pointer exception over here:

```
Known_Error_Subscription__c kes = kav.Known_Errors_Subscriptions__r;
kes.Knowledge__c = kav.KnowledgeArticleId;
```

because **kav.Known_Errors_Subscriptions__r** could be an empty list, so **kes.Knowledge__c = kav.KnowledgeArticleId;** would be referencing **Knowledge__c** on a non-existing **kes**.